# Display another DIV when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my `script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           function showlevel1() {
               var l1 = document.getElementById('default');
               l1.style.display = 'block';
               var l2 = document.getElementById('secondDiv');
               l2.style.display = 'none';
           }

           function showlevel2() {
               var l2 = document.getElementById('secondDiv');
               l2.style.display = 'block';
               var l1 = document.getElementById('default');
               l1.style.display = 'none';

           }
           function selectHandler(select) {

               if (select.value == 'count') {
                   showlevel2();

               } else if (select.value == 'Top') {
                   showlevel1();
               } 
           }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form>
<select id='type'>
<option value="Top">TOP</option>
<option value="count">COUNT</option>
</select>

<input type='submit' value='submit' onclick=selectHandler(this)>
</form>

<div id='default' style="display:block">
    <h1>Div 1</h2>
</div>

<div id='secondDiv' style="display:none">
    <h2> Div 2</h1>
</div>
```

When I load the page the `DIV 1` does shows up, since the property is set to `display:'Block'` but when I perform the selection from drop down it never changes to `DIV2` upon the `Count` selection from drop down and a submit click button?

Can anyone please help in figuring out the issue and let me know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `select.value` outputs `submit` since your this element referes to

-> `<input type="submit" value="submit"/>`

**Why**

`selectHandler(this)` is triggered by your `submit` button and not by your `<select>` tag, so when you perform `select.value` it returns `submit` as your text.

After seeing your question I guess you are in need of getting the `select` tag value.

Try this

```
function selectHandler(select) {
   // get your drop down list element i.e select tag
   var selected = document.getElementById('type');  
   if (selected.value === 'Count') {
      showlevel2();
   } 
   else if (selected.value === 'Top') {
      showlevel1();
   } 
}
```

**After seeing your comments**

The problem is your using `type="submit"` 
which posts to the same page when your click on it. Change it to `type="button"`

```
<input type='button' value='submit' onclick="selectHandler()">

function selectHandler() {
   // get your drop down list element i.e select tag
   var select = document.getElementById('type');  
   if (select.value === 'Count') {
      showlevel2();
   } 
   else if (select.value === 'Top') {
      showlevel1();
   } 
}
```

**Or**

```
<input type='submit' value='submit' onclick="return selectHandler()">

function selectHandler() {
   var select = document.getElementById('type');  
   if (select.value === 'Count')
      showlevel2();
   else if (select.value === 'Top') 
      showlevel1();
   return false;
}
```

js fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/QGsza/68/

Comment: it is like, when I am pressing the submit button it shows the other div, but stick to the first `div1` even after releasing the button. I think it is because of `<div id='div1' style="display:block'>` but I do need to show my `div1` when the page loads? can you suggest me how should I proceed??

Comment: Thank you niko, but I needed to use `submit` button to make a request from servlet and then later provide back the response to those `Divs` Do you know how can I achieve that or is it possible I can make the state persistent or something?

Comment: Thanks niko, I tried that too, its like when I submit I always see the `Div1` since its refreshing, but when i go back from the browser back button it shows the `DIV2` ?

Comment: It did let me show the second div :) but whatever things that needed to work doing submit button like getting the response from a servlet its now not displaying it. :(

Comment: Your actual question is solved :) @akiiddweeber I think you need to post a new question , I am not able to understand your requirement. please be more specific in your new question. Your asking the servelt but your question was not about that :)

Comment: Yes you are right :) I basically wanted to have things work on my submit button and help me show the results accordingly in respective divs.

Comment: I also solved the problem, I just had to do on my page `onload` and the function name it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Just taking a quick look, it seems that you have checked for a lowercase value 'count' instead of 'Count'.

i.e. replace

```
select.value == 'count'
```

with

```
select.value == 'Count'
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for correcting, my bad edited-still doesn't work! :(

Answer (score 0):

in your onclick on the button, you're passing "this" which would be a pointer to the button itself.

change it to  `document.getElementById('type')` because it looks like your selectHandler is expecting the select element

also, change the button from "submit" to "button" as submit will tell the browser to make a request.

Comment: do you mean something like this? `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick=selectHandler(document.getElementById('type'))` I am trying to do this but it gives error saying expression or tag required, can you correct me if this is right what I doing?

Comment: I am currently having a JSP page where I need to make a request avia submit button and show the response in one of those `div's` thus needed `Submit` button

Answer (score 0):

the first DIV:

`<div style="display:block;" id="first">`

the second DIV:

`<div style="display:none;" id="second">`

and on the function add:

`document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'none';`
`document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'block';`